# Java Native Packaging creates huge file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, native, packaging

Please note: I realize that *the point* of Java is the multi platform capability from its JAR files running on a JVM. The reason I began programming in Java is because of this capability, but I have been specifically asked to create a standalone application and so I would appreciate help in doing so.

**The question:**

I have recently created a Java application in the form of a JAR file and, using Netbeans Native Packaging, have packaged it as an exe installer. The JAR file is 300 KB, the exe installer is 45 MB. I expected some extra size because of the libraries which need to be included for standalone compatibility, but the size has been increased by over 150 times and this is unacceptable for my situation. I thought at first that the size was caused by loading some unnecessary libraries, but in a test, even after removing *every library*, the installer was still 40 MB.

Does anyone have any suggestions for alternative packaging (besides using Netbeans Native Packaging) or ways to create a standalone exe out of a JAR file with less significant size increases?

This may very well not be possible, and in that case I would appreciate any suggestions for alternative options that may be useful in this situation.

Comment: Netbeans Native Packaging creates packages that are truly standalone - the target machine doesn't even have to have JRE installed. That's why the size is so big.

Comment: So the question is: do you really need a standalone package, or do you just want to wrap your jar to an exe file?

Comment: I would like a standalone exe. Do you know of any ways to compress it or compile it to become smaller? Or perhaps i need to write in a different language to achieve a standalone exe.

Comment: JRE 7 takes up 145.5MB of disk space. You're doing well if it got reduced by 2/3 in the installer. The objectives of a standalone executable and a small executable are therefore irreconcilable if 'small' means < 145MB.

Comment: @EJP - Thank you I had not considered that Native Packaging is so large because it is basically a package containing *the entire JRE*. I thought that a installer would be created with only the libraries my program was using. But i assume that is not possible.

Comment: It's not possible in principle, because you can't really tell without executing the Java application exactly what it's going to use, because of Reflection. You could remove a few of the JRE tools but it won't make much of a difference. Your masters are just going to have to review one or other of those conflicting requirements. You could do it in C# relying on the CLR being installed, which it almost always is due to other software requiring it, but strictly speaking that's no different from relying on Java, which is also usually already present for the same reason.

Comment: You might want to look at JWS as an installation mechanism. It will take care of the Java installation separately.

Comment: @EJP - Thank you, i would like to look into JWS do you have any links which might be helpful?

Comment: It's part of Java: [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/index.html).

Comment: Great! Thank you